# Generating an algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, direct-sum

I am studying the wikipedia proof of the Frobenius theorem. At a certain point it is shown that the divisionalgebra $D$ can be composed by a direct sum: $D=\mathbb{R}\oplus V$, as $\mathbb{R}$-vector spaces where $V$ is a linear (vector)  subspace of $D$. Then in the final part of the proof they say this:

> Let $W$ be a subspace of $V$ that generates $D$ as an algebra and which is
>       minimal with respect to this property.

My question now revolves around this: How can a subspace of $V$ still manage to generate D? It would seem to me that $W$ could never generate the entrire algebra $D$, since $D=\mathbb{R}\oplus V$ implies you need the whole of $V$ to accomplish that?

Could someone please explain to me how this is possible?

-**Edit**- After reading the first answer and comment it has become clear to me that I need to expand my question. I would like to understand what it means when someone says *a vector space generates an algebra.*

Comment: You seem to be extremely focused on a very specific thing, so it'd be probably a good idea you write down the complete context  so that people will understand what's going on here. Anyway, and guessing a little, I'd say $\;D=\Bbb R\oplus V\;$ is a direct sum as $\;\Bbb R$-spaces (vector spaces), whereas the other part refers to *algebras*. For example, the polynomial ring $\;\Bbb R[x]\;$ is a cyclic $\;\Bbb R$-algebra, but an infinitely dimensional real vector space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true that no subspace of $V$, not even all of $V$ itself, can generate $D$ *as a vector space*. That's because the only operations available are addition and the vector space "scaling," and $V$ is closed under both of these.

However, if we throw in the algebra multiplication, things change completely. By taking sums and products of things in $V$, it is still possible to generate all of $D$.

For (a slightly tangential) example, $\Bbb R[x]=x\Bbb R\oplus W$ as $\Bbb R$ vector spaces for some subspace $W$, and yet the smallest $\Bbb R$ algebra containing $x\Bbb R$ is $\Bbb R[x]$, so it generates the entire polynomial ring as an algebra.

---

"$X$ generates $Y$ as a *something*" is usually defined to mean that $Y$ is the smallest *something* containing $X$ as a subset. Most algebraic structures are stable under intersection, so this is usually equivalent to saying "the intersection of all *somethings* containing $X$ is the *something* $Y$." $X$ can be any subset whatsoever, and if $Y$ is an algebra, then $X$ could be a subspace (or not).

For example, the smallest vector space containing $x$ in $\Bbb R[x]$ is just $x\Bbb R$. Thus $x$ generates $x\Bbb R$ as a vector space. But you can't get $x^2$ using only vector space operations: there is no way to escape x$\Bbb R$ with addition and scaling alone.

But the smallest $\Bbb R$ algebra in $\Bbb R[x]$ containing $x$ is all of $\Bbb R[x]$. Why should this be? Well unlike the last paragraph, an algebra containing $x$ must also contain $x^2$, $x^3$ and all the other powers, so any polynomial can be generated with $x$ and $\Bbb R$.

Comment: I can see where you are going with this, but it seems I need to also ask what is ment exactly by the word generates. You'll see that I've made an edit to the question for this pupose.

Comment: @Aal Added a bit more... let me know if I can elaborate further.

Comment: Very well explained thank you. I realy needed that last part to complete the picture.

Comment: I realize that it's been a while since you answered this question, however I was reading it back and something struck me. You claim that $\mathbb R[x]$ is the smallest algebra containing $x$. But how would you get to $1$ starting from $x$. Isn't the smallest algebra containing $x$: $\mathbb R[x]\ominus \mathbb R$?

Comment: @gebruiker careful, I said "the smallest $\Bbb R$-algebra containing $x$." That means you can use elements from both $\Bbb R$ and $x$ to generate new elements, including $1\in \Bbb R$. I don't just mean $\{xr\mid r\in \Bbb R\}$, if that's what you're saying. That's not what I mean with the notation "$\Bbb R[x]$". On the other hand, if you're just talking about a *rng* containing $x$, you would only have $x$, its powers, and integer multiples, and not even $1$. For the *subring* generated by $x$, you'd probably want $\Bbb Z[x]\subseteq \Bbb R[x]$.

Comment: Does that mean we should require the algebra to be unital, otherwise we can't really say $\mathbb R\subset A$, where $A$ is the algebra generated from $x$. Because (as far as my ignorance can tell) just starting whith $x$ means we also have $rx$ and $x^n$, and all linear combinations of that but nothing more. So no $1$. Am I making sense?

Comment: @gebruiker "The smallest $\Bbb F$ algebra generated by a subset $S$" is, by definition, the smallest subalgebra containing $F$ and $S$.

Comment: I see you edited your comment. I think I get it now. Thank you for you efforts.

Comment: @gebruiker No problem! Glad to help, if possible..